# Unbiased estimator for mean

Tags: mathematical-statistics, unbiased-estimator, definition

The question: Given a random sample $X_1,...,X_n$ show that $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is an unbiased estimator for $E(X_1)$.

My confusion: Given a statistical model $(\Omega,\Sigma,p_{\theta})$, where $p_{\theta}$ is a parameterized collection of probability measures, We define $E_{\theta}(X)=\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)p_{\theta}(d\omega)$, where $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$. If $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is unbiased, we need $E_{\theta}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)=\theta$, when $\theta=E(X_1)$. But what is $E(X_1)$? With respect to what measure are we integrating, if we're considering all these different measures on the space?

For any $\theta$, $E_{\theta}(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)=E_{\theta}(X_1)$, because each $X_i$ is identically distributed. My guess is, you would say something like, "for a fixed probability measure $p_{\varphi}$ on $(\Omega,\Sigma)$, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ is an unbiased estimator for $E_{\varphi}(X_1)$." Is this right?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Cross Validated. _"because each $X_i$ is identically distributed"_ probably should be mentioned at the top, because the "The question" statement is not necessarily true unless the i.i.d assumption holds. In fact, it might not even be true anyway (e.g. Cauchy distribution doesn't have a mean)

Comment: I think you're over-thinking the problem though. By definition, an estimator $S(X_1, \cdots X_n)$ is unbiased for some parameter $\theta$ if the expectation of the estimator equals the parameter value, i.e. $E[S]=\theta$. So in your case, it is sufficient to show that $E[\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i]=E[X_1]$.

Comment: You are greatly overcomplicating things.  With the i.i.d. assumption, as mentioned by @AlexJ, what is the expectation of $X_1 / n$?  of $X_2 / n$?   The sum of all the expectations?  How does the expectation operator work on sums?

Comment: My understanding is, one must allow for the density of the random variable to vary by some parameter. When you write $E(X_1)$, which measure are you integrating with respect to?

Comment: @jbowman It's simple linearity of the integral, but there are various measures to consider.

Comment: I believe one has to allow for the expectation to change, as the parameter $\theta$ varies.

Comment: No, there aren't.  (This is where the ":over-thinking the problem" comes in.)  You have an expected value, you don't need anything else but the i.i.d. assumption to solve this.

Comment: Here is the definition I've been using: An estimator $T$ is unbiased if $E(T)=\theta$, for *each* value of $\theta$. Now, if the measure isn't varying, this definition doesn't make sense, since $E(T)$ is a fixed constant, and $\theta$ is free to vary.

Comment: The measure is irrelevant.  You have an expected value $\theta$.  Is the expected value of the sample mean equal to that?  What is $E(X_1)$?  It is $\theta$.  What is $E(X_2)$?  It too is $\theta$.  What is $[E(X_1) + E(X_2)] / 2$ = 2\theta / 2?  It, too, is $\theta$.  And so forth.

Comment: Apologies, I'm not following. I'm with you once we are clear on what $E(X)$ means in this context. Then of course, $E(c_1X_1+...+c_nX_n)=E(X_1)$, for any convex combination, since they are identically distributed and have the same integral.

Comment: The measures are parameterized by $\theta$, which is the expected value.  Pick any measure, and the corresponding value of $\theta$ is the expected value of $X$ with respect to that measure.  It doesn't matter *which* one you pick because they are parameterized by $\theta$, and the proof holds for any $\theta$, not just one specific value of $\theta$ out of all the possible ones.   That's what makes it a useful proof - it's not tied to the distribution (except insofar, as @Alexj noted, as the distribution has to actually have an expected value.)

Comment: Ah! I think I understand. You're actually *choosing* a parameterization for the measures. You're not assuming this is any parameterization. Is that correct? Fix a measure $\mu$ on $\Omega$. Then to specify it via this particular parameterization, $\mu=\mu_{\theta}$, where $\theta$ is the parameter value $E_{\mu}(X)=\int_{\Omega}Xd\mu$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes!  And, since the proof holds at this generic level, it must be true for all distributions which can be parameterized by the expected value.

Comment: Ok, I'll have to consider it more, but what you're saying makes more sense and answers another question I had considered, "Can a statistic be unbiased with respect to one parameterization, but not another?" So is this what is generally going on then? Not just for the sample mean, but say $\theta$ was actually a vector, mean and variance. You're expressly choosing a parameterization first, and then showing the statistic is unbiased with respect to that parameterization?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  Consider the set of Gaussian distributions, parameterized by $\theta = (\mu, \sigma^2)$.  It's exactly the same situation; choose a $\theta$ (equivalent to choosing a Gaussian distribution from the set), and the sample mean of the  $X_i$ drawn from that distribution will be an unbiased estimator of $\mu$ (obviously $E(X) = \mu$ in this case.)

Comment: I appreciate your patience and knowledge! Thank you.

Comment: @jbowman, mind if you frame an answer out of your helpful comments here so that OP may accept it?

Comment: Also asked at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4871263/unbiased-estimator-of-sample-mean

Comment: @User1865345 - have done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have a collection of measures $p_{\theta}$, indexed by $\theta$, which is the expected value of the associated random variable (so random variables that don't have an expected value aren't in the collection.) Now, we pick a measure, any measure; having done so, the expected value is, in your notation,

$$E_{\theta}(X)=\int_{\Omega}X(\omega)p_{\theta}(d\omega)$$

which in turn equals the $\theta$ associated with $p_{\theta}$ by definition.  Having done so, the proof, as outlined in comments to the OP, is straightforward:

$E_{\theta}\left(\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i\right)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nE_{\theta}(X_1) = \frac{1}{n}\cdot n\theta = \theta$

Comment: Appreciate the quick response +1.